# Is it possible to adjust the opacity of the Visual Studio 2008 intellisense popups?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, transparency

In VS2008, you can hit CTRL to make an intellisense popup partially transparent so you can read the code under it.

Is it possible to adjust the degree of transparency somewhere? Like a registry key, for instance? I find the default translucency a bit too opaque and still struggle to read the code underneath.

Comment: And now that it has that extra delay it's more useless than ever before... I wish it had zero delay and was fully transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Searched a lot but couldnt find one. Even [Scottgu's blog post about intellisense](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/28/nice-vs-2008-code-editing-improvements.aspx) does not mention about this ;-) so I dont think there is an option for it.

But why dont you try changing [VS theme so that you can choose a better colour for your code](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2008/03/16/dark-colored-visual-studio-color-scheme.aspx) like the one shown below.

[alt text http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/rosherove/WindowsLiveWriter/DarkColoredVisualStudioColorScheme_C21F/image_3.png](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/rosherove/WindowsLiveWriter/DarkColoredVisualStudioColorScheme_C21F/image_3.png)

Some more themes [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx) from Scott's blog.

Coding Horror theme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, take the source code for my GPL VS add-in and modify it to your needs. One of its features *adds* this ability to VS 2005 using the same opacity as VS2008 uses. By default it's conditionally compiled in the VS2005 dll (SamTools2005.dll), so you'll need to compile it back in to the 2008 one using a modified opacity.

The source installs to the program files directory, or you can use a program like 7-zip to extract the .7z file from the msi installer itself.

[SamTools features](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:SamTools:Features) (which for some reason doesn't list the opacity modification)
[SamTools releases](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:SamTools:Releases)